# Selenium cant seem to find text on page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-8 no-padding-991" id="status">
  <b>Area:</b>
  157 Meters
  <sup>2</sup>
  | 1689.93 Feet
  <sup>2</sup>
  | 0.02 Ha | 0.04 Acres | 0 Miles
  <sup>2</sup> 
  | 0 Km
  <sup>2</sup>
  <br>
  <b>Perimeter:</b>
  56.06 Meters | 0.06 Km | 0.03 Miles | 184 Feet | 61.00 Yards 
</div>
```

I am trying to pull that value from the **Area:** tag yet for some reason, when I run this code:

```
print("scraping calc maps")
driver.get(url)

building_specs = driver.find_element_by_id("status")
print("Building specs")
print(building_specs.text)
```

It only pulls "Area: --", with no numbers.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please share your url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do:

```
print("scraping calc maps")
driver.get(url)

building_specs =   driver.find_element_by_id("status")
print("Building specs")
print(building_specs.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help! This works great, I will just have to do a little string manipulation since it returns everything within the status id instead of just the area.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, the .text attribute returns only the first text literal it finds. To get a concatenated text of all child nodes, you can query the `innerHTML` or `innerText` attribute:

```py
# get child HTML
print(building_specs.get_attribute("innerHTML"));
# get child Text
print(building_specs.get_attribute("innerText"));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! The second one seemed to produce the same issue, but the "innerHTML" worked great.